# How do I get the max value from the "nb" column"?

Tags: php, mysql, count, max

Here is how I m getting my first result :

```
SELECT PageName, COUNT(DISTINCT Ip) as nb FROM statistique INNER JOIN visite ON statistique.Id = visite.IdPage GROUP BY statistique.Id;
```

And this is what I'm getting : PageName nb /edsa-PHP/index.php 1 /edsa-PHP/test2.php 1 /PHP/index.php 3 /PHP/test2.php 1

```
PageName              nb
/edsa-PHP/index.php   1
/edsa-PHP/test2.php   1
/PHP/index.php        3
/PHP/test2.php        1
```

This is how I think I can get the max value of the count :

```
SELECT MAX(nb) FROM (SELECT PageName, COUNT(DISTINCT Ip) as nb FROM statistique INNER JOIN visite ON statistique.Id = visite.IdPage GROUP BY PageName) AS t;
```

Comment: `ORDER BY nb DESC LIMIT 1` the short way

Comment: and the selcet and sub select must have the same count of selects `PageName, MAX(nb)` if you want to get it work

Comment: Awkward thing, phpMyAdmin was telling me that the query was wrong but when executing that was working.

Comment: Shame on me, thanks to you !

Comment: use a tool like heidisql that has some nice debug console ;)